# Where can I find the robots.txt file in Craft 3?

Tags: craft3

I can't find it in the web folder or anywhere else, but its there when I visit the file in the browser.

Comment: Shot in the dark but... if you're using [SEOmatic](https://nystudio107.com/plugins/seomatic) it will generate that file for you. You edit it via SEOmatic -> Global SEO -> Robots

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so my hosting provider Hyperlane overwrites the robots.txt as long as you visit the file on their address. The file should be in the web/ folder and will show up when you visit it with your domain.